# Is it safe to sleep computer while updating software?

Tags: updates, sleep

Update is taking a long time but I need to close the lid of my laptop and go (I'm not upgrading version, just a regular update). Is this safe?

Comment: I suggest you just kill the screen if that is the problem.

Comment: If Jorge Castro answer worked for you please accept it. If you don't do this, people might not want to answer your questions in the future. It also cleans the statistics up so we know what questions has a working answer or not.

Answer (score 11):

Probably not.

If it's still just downloading the updates then interrupting it is fine, but if the package manager has already started unpacking files then don't interrupt it.

Best case interrupting the package manager will require doing a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, worst case you interrupt it while updating the boot loader or something and that can be bad.